# How to use endpoint status code to authenticate a user?

Tags: angular, authentication, service, components, endpoint

I'm trying to make so that my Angular app will detect what status code my endpoint is outputting and act upon it.  If its `status 200` ok then the program should do one action. If not, it'll do another.

Here's my approach:

**Login.service.ts**

```
login() {
      return this.http.post(this._url , null, { observe: 'response' });
```

This code should observe the endpoint and get `status code 200` ok, right? If so...

**login.component.ts**

```
logInUser() {
    this._LoginService.login().subscribe(
      (response: any)=>{
        if (response.status == 200) {
          console.log(response);
        this.location.replaceState('/tool');
        this.router.navigate(['/tool']);
    }
    (err) => {
      console.log("oops"+err.status);
      alert("There was a problem logging you out");
      console.log("userName " + this.userName);
      console.log("userPass " + this.userPass);
      
    }
  }
  );
 }
```

The login method from login.service.ts will send the status code to this `LogInUser` method in l`ogin.component.ts` and if it's 200 ok, the user will redirect to another page. Otherwise, the user will stay on the current page and alert the user.

However trying this approach yields this error:
[Secondary endpoint error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmsrJ.png)

While the first `/authn` endpoint in the listed returns 200 Ok status code, A secondary endpoint `/authn` pops up saying 400 bad request.

I tried the approach above and expected the code to do as I expected/explained but it doesn't appear to work. Not sure where I'm going wrong but I'd appreciate if someone could help me revise this approach so it works as expected.

Comment: What's the difference between the 2 calls? Same URL? What's in the *Preview* and *Response* tabs of the failed call? Why is it called twice?